# Store Randomly Selected date in a Variable in Jquery Calender

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store randomly selected value from calender in x and print it.... but with my code only the default todays value is getting stored in "X"...

i want to store the selected date from jquery calender in a variable...... date value in the variable should change automatically when we click on other date.....

```
Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker_send" name="datepicker_send" readonly="readonly"  >
<script>
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
        altField: '#datepicker_send',
            inline: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
    });
</script>
<script>  
    var x = document.getElementById('datepicker_send').value;
    document.write (x);    
</script>
```

Comment: sorry... what are you looking for

Comment: do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/D4AGz/141/

Comment: i want to store the selected date from jquery calender in a variable...... date value in the variable should change automatically when we click on other date.....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/D4AGz/142/

Comment: $('#calendar').datepicker({
 
 altField: '#datepicker_send',

  inline: true,

  firstDay: 1,

  showOtherMonths: true,

  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']

 }).on('select', function() {
 var x=  document.write ($('#datepicker_send').val());
 alert("x");
   });

Answer (score 0):

Use Datepicker onSelect Event to pick the changed date. For more details 
[DatePicker OnSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

Edit:

`$('#datepicker_send').datepicker({
    altField: '#datepicker_send',
    inline: true, firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    onSelect: function(){
        var selected_date = $('#datepicker_send').val();
        alert("selected date="+selected_date);
    }
});`

Comment: $('#calendar').datepicker({
 
 altField: '#datepicker_send',

  inline: true,

  firstDay: 1,

  showOtherMonths: true,

  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
 }).on('select', function() {
 var x=  document.write ( $('#datepicker_send').val());
 alert("x");
});...... is this the correct way??